# black box while play video in flask

Tags: flask, video

I use flask to show video, but it came to a black box....
html is below:

```
<div>
    <video controls = "controls">
        <source src="{{ url_for('static',filename = 'video/' + user_speed.filename) }}" type="video/mp4" >
    </video>
</div>
```

the flask return  "GET /static/video/keyframe_ivan9394_3337c6ac-5ede-4ca3-ac35-77e787b7c66c.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 -

when i check my edge, i found the video is not transmited proberbly, only 2-3 fractions within 1000 kb

I have tried clean the browser cache, add threaded = True in the app.run()...